# Unicode combined stroke character ends up on the wrong height?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, python-unicode

I have a string like "€1,49" and I would want to have that striked through with unicode. I know that this should be possible with [U+0336](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0336/index.htm), which I am applying to my string (in Python) like this:

```
'\u0336'.join('€1,49') + '\u0336'
```

The problem is that this ends up striking the comma at a different hight from the rest of the string, thereby killing the illusion of a clean strikethrough (see the screenshot).[image: screenshot]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot do it.

You are looking for formatting, which it is outside unicode scope. You should do with control character (if your terminal support it), or with html, or other means.

You are using a function created mostly to modify existing characters (and of the same type).

Note: Unicode also do not define the output, and so the above output depend on the font, and it may not work on many different environment.

You may get a better results byt replacing the comma, with comma and some combining characters (space like), so that font will see the combination as higher character, and so a more aligned strike. But as I wrote, it is not really portable and it depends on your font, so I cannot test and give you a good solution. [And as I say before, it is bad taste to use U+0336 for such formatting scope]

Comment: BTW on my terminal, I get the line centered, but just discontinuous between the different letters. But most of fonts show it as a continuous line. OTOH I do not find fonts with your behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is indeed highly platform- and/or font-dependent. I thought I could use this for a system that has no other way of formatting text, but I guess this would not end well.